# How can I get lookup field value from VF page？

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

After I created a case and choose lookup field value(AccountId), I wanna get the value in my controller, but the field always return null.
 [image: VF page]

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" tabStyle="Case" extensions="NewCase">

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="getAcctid" action="{! getAcctid}" />
</apex:form>

<script>
    function changeVal(){
        //getAcctid();
        document.getElementById('{! $Component.myForm.myBlock.myBlockSection.test}').value = '{! casex.accountid}';
        document.getElementById('{! $Component.myForm.myBlock.myBlockSection.test2}').value = '{! acctId}';
    }
</script> 

<apex:sectionHeader title="New Case" subtitle="Case Edit"/>
<apex:form styleClass="slds" id="myForm">
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Case Edit" id="myBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{! Save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save & Close" action="{! SaveAndClose}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" action="{! SaveAndNew}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" reRender="a,test" onclick="changeVal()" action="{! getAcctid}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageblockSection title="Case Information" collapsible="false" columns="2">
            <apex:outputField value="{! owner.Name}" />
            <apex:inputfield value="{! casex.status}"/>  
            <apex:inputField id="Contact" value="{! casex.contactid}"/>  
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.Priority}"/>
            <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{! casex.Accountid}" onchange="changeVal()" />
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.origin}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.Type}" /><p/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.reason}"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Additional Information" collapsible="false" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.Product__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.EngineeringReqNumber__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.PotentialLiability__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.SLAViolation__c}"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Description Information" collapsible="false" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField id="mySub" value="{! casex.Subject}" style="width: 58%"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! casex.Description}" style="width: 60%"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Optional" collapsible="false" id="myBlockSection">
            <apex:panelgroup >
                <apex:inputcheckbox value="{! isprivate}" selected="true" label="hello"/>
                <apex:outputtext value="test"/>
            </apex:panelgroup>

            <apex:inputText id="test" />
            <apex:inputText id="test2" value="{! acctId}"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{! casex.accountid}" id="a"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

```
public class NewCase {

public Case casex{get;set;}
public Integer flag{get;set;}
public String username{get;set;}
public User owner{get;set;}
public Id acctId{get;set;}

private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

public NewCase(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    this.controller = controller;

    flag = 1;
    Account acct = null;
    casex = new Case();

    casex.put('subject','test');

    acctId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('def_account_id');
    if(acctId == null)
            flag = 2;
    else{
        casex.put('accountid', (Object)acctId);
    }

    username = UserInfo.getName();    
}

public PageReference Save(){
    insert casex;
    return null;
}

public PageReference SaveAndClose(){
    insert casex;
    return controller.cancel();
}

public PageReference SaveAndNew(){
    insert casex;
    casex = new Case();
    casex.put('accountid',(Object)acctId);

    return null;
}

public PageReference Close(){
    return controller.cancel();
}

public PageReference getAcctid(){
    system.debug(casex.accountid);
    system.debug(casex.Subject);
    return null;
    } 
}
```

Result: DEBUG|null

Comment: I believe it will be easier to debug if you can some some relevant code. Is this a VF page?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: @manjit_singh hi, dude,  I have pasted my test code.

Comment: @Samir ok, I have pasted my test code

Answer (score 1):

There are some required field in your code thats why value does not pass from page to controller. You need to fill that or can use `actionregion` to pass the value.

Something like

```
<apex:actionRegion> 
     <apex:inputField value="{!casex.Accountid}">              
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getAcctid}" rerender="additionalinfo"/>              
      </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
```